# Click to Delete html and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have two divs side by side, the first one contains a table of information the other will contain two buttons a delete and edit. The first div I want to be 100% of the screen the second will be off the screen to start with then once I click the first div with the table the second will slide out and push the first div over and show the delete and edit buttons

```
<div id="div1">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Some Information</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
<div id="div2">
   <button id="delete"></button>
   <button id="edit"></button>
</div>
//Javascript Code
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#div1').click(function {
         //slide div2 out and push div1 to the left to show delete and edit buttons
      });
   });
</script>
```

I am trying to make it similar to the iOS mail app where you can swipe to delete but instead you will click and if you click again div1 will push div2 off the screen so basically I want to toggle the delete and edit div on and off the screen.

Not sure what javascript and css is involved in this. Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like such structure the actionable elements in a div which will then be shifted around based on the state.

```
<div id="div2">
    <div class="inner">
       Fusce fermentum
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <button id="delete"></button>
        <button id="edit"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Have #div2 be position:relatve;

```
#div2 {
    background: #eeeeee;
    padding: 20px 80px 20px 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.actions {
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    right: -60px;
    top: 0;
    transition: right 0.2s ease-in-out;
    width: 60px;
}

.reveal .actions {
    right: 0;
}
```

Then just toggle the class with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div2').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('reveal');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P6gAe/1/

Answer (score 0):

And this to your head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Add this to your script

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "#div1" ).hide( "drop", { direction: "up" }, 500 );
});



});
```